# Javascript Add two Integer Variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to create something where when a user clicks a div element, it adds a number to a total, sort of like a checkout system.

I have written the following javascript

**JS**

```
        var optionOne = 5;
        var optionTwo = 10;

        var basePrice = 0;
        function doMath() {
            $("#option1checkout").click(function() {
                // Add optionOne to basePrice
            });
            $("#option1cancel").click(function() {
                // Don't do anything to basePrice
            });
            $("#option2checkout").click(function() {
                // Add optionTwo to basePrice
            });
            $("#option2cancel").click(function() {
                // Don't do anything to basePrice
            });
        };
```

I want it to add option 1 and 2 to basePrice whenever they click the option1checkout or option2checkout div element and do nothing when they click the cancel div elements.
I just feel like if I just do "basePrice + optionOne;" in the click functions it would be manual and not actually adding the integer values.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: `it would be manual and not actually adding the integer values.` I don't understand this. What's your problem? What's wrong with `basePrice+=optionOne` or `basePrice+=optionTwo` for each click?

Answer (score 1):

What wrong with this approach:

```
  var mousePrice = 5;
  var coverPrice = 10;
  var mouseSelected=0;
  var coverSelected=0;
  var basePrice = 500;
    function doMath() {
        $("#mouse").click(function() {
            basePrice+=mousePrice;
        });
        $("#omouseCancel").click(function() {
           if(mouseSelected>0){
               basePrice-=(mousePrice*mouseSelected);
            }
        });
        $("#cover").click(function() {
            basePrice+=coverPrice;
        });
        $("#coverCancel").click(function() {
           if(coverSelected>0){
               basePrice-=(coverPrice*coverSelected);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Because what if they want to add another item. Say you choose optionOne but also want optionTwo, wouldn't the output of basePrice change from 5 to 10 as you select one?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement more. Is it like you select one main product (say laptop) and then you have list of other tools like mouse , cover ? and you want to calculate the sum of base price and other selected options to calculate the checkout amount